# 70D mov import to DaVinci Resolve 12 appear darker

Tags: davinci-resolve

I import mov files from Canon 70D to Davinci Resolve 12 and it appears darker on the preview than if I run the video on VLC video player.

I render the video and the output is the same as on the preview (darker than VLC).

I also shoot jpg for reference and look the same as the video on VLC.

I am using nvideo video card on windows 10.

What should I do to make it consistent?

Comment: Can you post screenshots for reference?